# Is it possile to set time before windows disable device for energy saving purposes?

Tags: windows, power-management, time, device-manager, energy-saving

I have a tablet-pc with Windows 8 and dock keyboard. Windows disables dock keyboard after ~10 seconds of downtime by default. I want to increase that time to 60 seconds at least. Is it possible somehow? I don't want to turn off energy saving feature.

Answer (score 0):

Type "Power options" in the search to get the screen of the control panel. Then select your power plan and click on "advanced" to configure this sort of thing.